# What is Fedora's equivalent of deborphan?

Tags: fedora, package-management

An installed library that has no installed packages depending on it is referred to as **orphaned**. One of the tools used to determine which libraries are orphaned on a Debian system is named [deborphan](http://packages.debian.org/sid/deborphan). What is the Fedora equivalent?

Comment: Since this question is not really to do with Debian (merely using it as an illustration), would you kindly remove the 'debian' tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that [package-cleanup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/package-cleanup) can perform a similar task with the following command:

```
$ package-cleanup --leaves
```

or, to include more than just libraries

```
$ package-cleanup --leaves --all
```

`package-cleanup` is in [yum-utils](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumUtils) package, which is available for installation via the Fedora repositories.